# Access to edit HTML Template

Tags: profile, insufficient-privileges

how to give access to a user for html email template for sales profile. when he is trying to create a email template he gets below error

> Insufficient Privileges
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation
> you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your
> administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see
> Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following permission required for [creating and editing HTML email template](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_html_email_templates.htm):

> To create or change HTML email templates: “Edit HTML Templates”

If you don’t have permission to edit public templates, go to your personal settings. Enter Templates in the Quick Find box, then select Email Templates or My Templates—whichever one appears.

This permission can be provided through permission set or profile as well.You just need to search permission **Edit HTML Templates** under **System permissions** of permission set or **Administrative Permissions** of profile.